# Case Reason on Case Close layout

Tags: case, servicecloud, case-object

Salesforce has just one Case Reason field to show on case creation and case closure layouts. I think it makes senses to show different set of values during closure. I did some research and found that it is not possible to show different values for case closure.

I was wondering how can customize it? Should I create a new custom "Reason" field for case closure.

Would appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Case Reason is a picklist field and you can add custom values based on your requirements into this picklist. Salesforce allows that.

In case if you need additional field like "Reason for Closure" (textarea) then add this field into Case Close Page Layout.

Comment: Thanks. I know I can edit the picklist but we have "case reason" field on create layout also. it does not make sense to show closure related values during case creation.

Comment: You can filter out those based on recordtype during case creation. Secondly, during case creation, do you really need to show reason field?